# java regular expression , how to add '[' to expression

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I want to create a regular expression for strings which uses special characters `[` and `]`.

Value is `"[action]"`.

Expression I am using is `"[\\[[\\x00-\\x7F]+\\]]"`.

I tried doing it by adding `\\` before `[` and `]`.

But it doesn't work.

Can any one help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to remove the enclosing brackets "[]". In regexps they mean a choice of one of the enclosed characters

Comment: Like this, it would seem: "\\\[[\\x00-\\x7F]+\\\]".

Answer (score 1):

Two backslashes before the open and close brackets: `\\[` and `\\]`

The double backslash evaluates a single backslash in the string. The single backslash escapes the brackets so that they are not interpreted as surrounding a character class.

No backslashes for the brackets that do declare the character class: `[a-z]` (you can you any range you like, not just a to z)

The [Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) operator matches any number of characters in the range.

```
public class Regexp {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println("[action]".matches("\\[[a-z]*\\]"));
    }
}
```

On my system:

```
$ javac Regexp.java && java Regexp
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stick one backslash before the square bracket.

Two backslashes escapes itself, so the regex engine sees `\[`, where `[` is a special char.

Comment: This is a Java string literal, so he needs double backslashes in order for the "regex engine" to see a single backslash.

Comment: Ah right, my bad, I guess I'm used to typing regexes in a C# verbatim string.